# JS - Como adicionar uma style dentro de uma nova classe?

Tags: javascript, html, css

É possível com javascript adicionar um elemento a uma classe?

EX: Tenha uma classe:

```
.post_22 {color:red}
```

Até então ela só tem color, mas quando clicar em um link:

```
<a onclick="minBox()">Seu Poste</a>
```

teria como adicionar a CLASSE **post_22** outro estilo?

Sei que da pra utilizar com `css()`, mas na tela há um `setInterval`, oque quer dizer que quando ele atualizar novamente iria remover o `css()` que estaria atribuído a classe através do css(), nesse caso se poder atribuir direto na classe não seria removida no próximo `setInterval`.

Lembrando que a classe `post_22` elá não existe de fato no arquivo css, ela poderá ser `post_1`, `post_2`, `post_3`.... isso vem de acordo com o `ID` no servidor vinculado ao poste.

Se no servidor o `ID` do poste: *"Ola meu amigo."*  for **"ID: 66"** ele gera a class `post_` e junta com o ID `post_66`

Comment: Você pode colocar um exemplo no https://jsfiddle.net e compartilhar?

Comment: Não vejo como criar um exemplo a isso. Oque realmente preciso, é que quando clicar no link **<a onclick="minBox()">Seu Poste</a>** seja adicionado um estilo diretamente uma classe.. em vez de user css() que cai no atributo "style".

Comment: Você esta usando jQuery?

Comment: sim, @Gerep deu pra entender a ideia?

Comment: Você quer adicionar uma nova classe `CSS` no seu link, é isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa tarde não ha como  você alterar o estylo de uma classe o que você pode fazer é usar

```
$("#ElelementoId").css({"body":"Value","outro":"valor"});
```

ou caso você queira escrever no html uma classe você pode fazer o seguinte

```
$("head").append("<style>.minhaclasse{aqui o  meu estilo}</style>");
```

Comment: Boa ideia, Testando...

Comment: blz se funcionar da um up qui  e marca  como melhor resposta boa sorte

Comment: Boa, a do `append` nem passou pela minha cabeça. +1

Answer (score 3):

Sim, utilizando o `css` como você mesmo já mencionou:

```
$('.classe').css('propriedade', 'valor')
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function RefreshClass(){
    $('.classe').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
}

RefreshClass();

function minBox(){
  $('div').append(
    $('<p />').addClass('classe').text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi voluptates veritatis inventore voluptatum magnam sed voluptas perferendis porro doloremque quidem natus iste ipsa. Dolore nostrum illo odit dolor incidunt fuga.')
  );

  // Atualiza a Classe novamente.
  RefreshClass();
}
```

```css
.classe{
    font-family:Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="minBox()">Postar</button>

<div></div>
```

**Obs.:** Todo o código aqui pode ser reproduzido sem jQuery.

Comment: Sim, mas como eu havia mencionado, existe um `setInverval`. E quando ele fizer um novo retorno o `style="text-decoration: underline;"` que esta atribuído vai ser removido porque ele não existia antes. @Kaduamaral

Comment: Basta adicionar a chamada da função `RefreshClass` dentro da `setInterval` @PedroQuezado

Answer (score 0):

Em seu css, utilize algo como:

```
a[class*='post'] {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Esse regra no seu css aplicará o que desejar a todos os elementos a com uma classe que o nome contenha "post".

[Exemplo no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rocmartinz/dy4d2Lr2/)